# Pass a char array to a function that uses File as parameter

Tags: arduino-uno, sd-card, array, compiler

I am in serious need for help here. I have a rather small function that get's the number of files from within a given directory. Now, the directory name (that is the path) is stored in a char array within my main loop.

My problem is, I have no idea how to pass this char array to my function.

This is my code (it's of course just a subset but it's the part that is obviously wrong) and you can also see the complete program at the end:

In the setup() routine I define my current working directory:

```
char plrCurrentFolder[9];
```

In the main loop I want to get the number of files of a given directory (in the final program this directory name will come from an NFC tag):

```
String temp = "findorie";
temp.toCharArray(plrCurrentFolder, 9);
unsigned int numberOfFiles = countFiles(plrCurrentFolder);
```

This is the function to return the number of files:

```
unsigned int countFiles(File dir){
  unsigned int counter = 0;
  while (true){
    File entry = dir.openNextFile();
    if (!entry){
      // no more files
      break;
    }
    counter++;
    entry.close();
  }
  dir.close();
  return counter;
}
```

To be honest I have two issues with this. First, I don't really like to create a temp String variable to create the char array here as I would rather stick with the char array in itself to safe on memory and maybe this would also aid in performance (although I'm not sure about that).

**Second, The way this whole thing is structured right now, it simply doesn't work. When building, the compiler correctly complains:**

```
exit status 1
could not convert '(char*)(& plrCurrentFolder)' from 'char*' to 'SDLib::File'
```

Can anyone help me out and give me a code snippet how to make this work???

Kind regards to all,

Christian

--- below you may find the complete code as of now ---

```
/*
 * Fairytale Main program
 * 
 * This programm will read an nfc tag. It will check for a directory name and optional a filename 
 * and start playing this on the music maker shield.
 * 
 * Restrictions:
 * 1. All filenames mus be in the format  trackXXX.mp3  - where XXX is a numbering from 001 to 999
 * 2. All directory names must be exactly 8 chars long
 * 
 */

// make sure to change this to 0 before uploading in production as it turns on lots and lots of serial messages
#define DEBUG 1
// we only show light effects, in case this is set to 1
#define LIGHTEFFECTS 0
// we only use the nfc reader if this is set to 1
#define NFCREADER 0

//
// setup SPI, MP3 and SD libraries
//
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_VS1053.h>
#include <SD.h>
// These are the pins used for the music maker shield
#define SHIELD_RESET  -1     // VS1053 reset pin (unused!)
#define SHIELD_CS     7      // VS1053 chip select pin (output)
#define SHIELD_DCS    6      // VS1053 Data/command select pin (output)
#define CLK 13 // SPI Clock, shared with SD card
#define MISO 12 // Input data, from VS1053/SD card
#define MOSI 11 // Output data, to VS1053/SD card

// These are common pins between breakout and shield
#define CARDCS 4     // Card chip select pin
// DREQ should be an Int pin, see http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt
#define DREQ 3       // VS1053 Data request, ideally an Interrupt pin

Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer musicPlayer = 
  // create shield-example object!
  Adafruit_VS1053_FilePlayer(SHIELD_RESET, SHIELD_CS, SHIELD_DCS, DREQ, CARDCS);


//
// setup NFC Adapter 
//
#ifdef NFCREADER
/*
  #include <PN532_SPI.h>
  #include <PN532.h>
  #include <NfcAdapter.h>

  #define PN532_SCK (13) //changed from pin 2
  #define PN532_MISO (12) //changed from pin 5
  #define PN532_MOSI (11) //changed from pin 3
  #define PN532_SS (10) //changed from 4

  PN532_SPI pn532spi(SPI, PN532_SS);
  NfcAdapter nfc = NfcAdapter(pn532spi);
*/
#endif

// these variables are used for the light effects
int lightValue1, lightValue2, lightValue3;
const int redPin = 7;
const int greenPin = 8;
const int bluePin = 9;


// these are timing counters for the light effects
long time=0;
int periode = 20000;
int displace = 500;

// uptime counters
unsigned int runCounter = 0;
unsigned long startUpTime = 0;
const unsigned long maxUpTime = 120000; // 1800000L;  // 30 Minutes


// these are variables for the nfc card
boolean cardScanned = false;    // did we already scan the card?? using this to suppress reading in the card data while it is on the reader
char cardId[16];                // the uid of the card as read in through the nfc reader


// mp3 player variables
boolean plrIsPlaying = false;                         // is the mp3 player already playing?
char plrCurrentFile[13];                              // which track is the player playing?
char plrNextFile[13];                                 // which track is the player playing?
char plrPrevFile[13];                                 // which track is the player playing?
char plrCurrentFolder[9];                             // which directory is the player playing?
uint8_t plrCurrentPosition = 0;                       // on which position in seconds are we in the current track?
char currentTrackFileName[] = "/system/current.txt";  // a file we might use to store the last played track


// volume control variables for the analog poti
int volumePotPin = A0;        // the analog input pin that we use for the potentiometer
int sensorDrift = 7;          // difference to last received sensor value that must be exceeded to activate a change in the volume
int compareValue = 0;         // just a convenience variable to make comparison easier
int sensorValue = 0;          // read the value from the potentiometer
int lastSensorValue = 0;      // keeps the last read sensor value
uint8_t soundVolume = 0;      // the sound volume is derived via a map function from the sensor value

// other button settings
int btnLinePin = A1;         // pin on which the button line (4 buttons) is connected
int btnVal = 0;


// these are the prototypes for the nfc card reader
void getNfcCardData();


// these are the prototypes for the mp3 player controller
uint8_t getVolume(void);        // function that returns the volume setting based on the analog read
char plrNext(void);             // play next file in album
char plrPrev(void);             // play previous file in album
void plrPlayTrack(char, char);  // play a single track
void setupSound(void);          // initializes the sound system and plays the startup sound

// these are the prototypes to work on files
void printDirectory(File, int);   // print out the content of specified directory on serial console
unsigned int countFiles(File);    // return the number of files in a directory passed as a File descriptor
//unsigned int countFiles(char[]);    // return the number of files in a directory passed as a File descriptor


// these are the prototypes for the light effects
void fader(void);
void startuplight(void);
void highlight(int);
void flash(int);
void pulse(int);


void setup() {
  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.begin(115200);
  #endif

  plrCurrentFile[0] = 0; // we initialize the fiirst element of the array to 0 to later check if a current file was given.

  // initialise the music player
  if (! musicPlayer.begin()) { // initialise the music player
    #ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.println(F("Couldn't find VS1053, do you have the right pins defined?"));
    #endif
    while (1);
  }
  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println(F("Music Maker Shield VS1053 found"));
  #endif

  //musicPlayer.sineTest(0x44, 500);    // Make a tone to indicate VS1053 is working

  if (!SD.begin(CARDCS)) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.println(F("failed to detect the SD-Card"));
    #endif
    while (1);  // don't do anything more
  }
  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("SD found and operational");
  #endif

  // set the buttons as input
  pinMode(volumePotPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(btnLinePin, INPUT);

  // setup music maker shield and start playing startup file
  setupSound();

  #ifdef DEBUG
    // list files
    printDirectory(SD.open("/"), 0);
  #endif

/*
  // now as the last thing, start the nfc reader
  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.print("initializing NFC TAG reader ... "); 
  #endif
  nfc.begin();
  delay(1000); // wait some time for
*/

  // check our current time, so we know when to stop
  startUpTime = millis();
  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("we are up and running and ready to play audio"); 
  #endif
}


//
//      LL       OOOOOO    OOOOOO   PPPPPPP
//      LL      OO    OO  OO    OO  PP    PP
//      LL      OO    OO  OO    OO  PP    PP
//      LL      OO    OO  OO    OO  PPPPPP
//      LLLLLL   OOOOOO    OOOOOO   PP
void loop() {
  #ifdef LIGHTEFFECTS
    // turn off all the lights. we only want to have fading lights, while the playr is active
    //analogWrite(redPin, 0);
    //analogWrite(greenPin, 0);
    //analogWrite(bluePin, 0);
  #endif

  // NFC Tag reader functions
  // now we only do this, when an nfc tag is present
/*  
  if (nfc.tagPresent()){
    Serial.println("NFC tag Found!\n");
    NfcTag tag = nfc.read();
    Serial.print("Tag Type: ");
    Serial.println(tag.getTagType());
    Serial.print("UID: ");
    Serial.println(tag.getUidString());

    getNfcCardData();
*/  

    String temp = "findorie";
    temp.toCharArray(plrCurrentFolder, 9);


    // now let's get the number of files in the album directory
    //unsigned int numberOfFiles = 0;
    unsigned int numberOfFiles = countFiles(plrCurrentFolder);
    #ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.print("Directory ");Serial.print(plrCurrentFolder);Serial.print(" contains ");Serial.print(numberOfFiles);Serial.println(" files");
    #endif

    // if we did not get the current file from the tag, we are hardcoding it to track001.mp3
    if ((plrCurrentFile[0] == 0)) { 
      temp = "track001.mp3";
      temp.toCharArray(plrCurrentFile, 13);
    }

    #ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.print("currentFolder holds: ");Serial.print(plrCurrentFolder);Serial.print(" / currentFile contains: ");Serial.print(plrCurrentFile);
    #endif

    temp = "/";
    temp.concat(plrCurrentFolder);
    temp.concat("/");
    temp.concat(plrCurrentFile);
    char filename[temp.length() + 1];
    temp.toCharArray(filename, sizeof(filename));
    Serial.print(" / filename contains: ");Serial.println(filename);

    if (SD.exists(filename)) {
      Serial.print(filename);Serial.println(" exists.");

      // mp3 player functions playback
      // Start playing a file, then we can do stuff while waiting for it to finish
      if (! musicPlayer.startPlayingFile(filename)) {
        #ifdef DEBUG
          Serial.print("Could not open file ");Serial.println(filename);
        #endif
        while (1);
      }
      #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.print(F("Start playing "));Serial.println(filename);
      #endif

      while (musicPlayer.playingMusic) {
        // file is now playing in the 'background' so now's a good time
        // to do something else like handling LEDs or buttons :)

        // play some nice light effects, if wanted
        #ifdef LIGHTEFFECTS
          //fader();
        #endif

        // volume control functions
        // read the input on analog pin 0 and check if we have a change in volume.
        sensorValue = analogRead(volumePotPin);
        if (lastSensorValue > sensorValue) {compareValue = lastSensorValue - sensorValue;} else {compareValue = sensorValue - lastSensorValue;}
        // If we have a high enough difference in the sensor reading, calculate it so we may set it on the player
        if (compareValue > sensorDrift){
          #ifdef DEBUG
            Serial.print("changing volume: ");
          #endif
          soundVolume = getVolume();
          musicPlayer.setVolume(soundVolume,soundVolume);
        }
      }
      #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.println("Done playing ");Serial.println(filename);
      #endif
      #ifdef LIGHTEFFECTS
        //startuplight();
      #endif
    } else {
      Serial.print(filename);Serial.println(" does not exist.");
    } // end of file does not exist

  //} // end of tag found
} // end of loop


//
//        NN    NN  FFFFFF   CCCCCC
//        NNNN  NN  FF      CC
//        NN  N NN  FFFF    CC
//        NN  NNNN  FF      CC
//        NN    NN  FF       CCCCCC
//  BELOW THIS LINE THE NFC CONTROL IS DEFINED
//
void getNfcCardData(){
/*
  NfcTag tag = nfc.read();
  boolean usableContent = false;
  if (tag.hasNdefMessage()){
    NdefMessage message = tag.getNdefMessage();

    // If you have more than 1 Message then it wil cycle through them
    int recordCount = message.getRecordCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < recordCount; i++) {
      NdefRecord record = message.getRecord(i);

      int payloadLength = record.getPayloadLength();
      byte payload[payloadLength];
      record.getPayload(payload);

      String payloadAsString = ""; // Processes the message as a string vs as a HEX value
      for (int c = 0; c < payloadLength; c++) {
        payloadAsString += (char)payload[c];
      }

      String cleanString = payloadAsString;
      cleanString.remove(0,3);
      #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.print("content element "); Serial.print(i); Serial.print(": "); Serial.println(cleanString);
      #endif

      // now populate the vars for the player
      int spacePosition = cleanString.indexOf(':');
      if (cleanString.charAt(spacePosition - 1) == 'A') {
        String contentString = cleanString.substring(3);
        #ifdef DEBUG
          Serial.print("Album info: ");Serial.println(contentString);
        #endif
      }
      if (cleanString.charAt(spacePosition - 1) == 'D') {
        usableContent = true;
        String contentString = cleanString.substring(3);
        plrCurrentFolder = contentString;
        #ifdef DEBUG
          Serial.print("Directory: ");Serial.println(contentString);
        #endif
      }
      if (cleanString.charAt(spacePosition - 1) == 'T') {
        String contentString = cleanString.substring(3);
        plrCurrentFile = contentString;
        #ifdef DEBUG
          Serial.print("Track: ");Serial.println(contentString);
        #endif
      }
      if (cleanString.charAt(spacePosition - 1) == 'P') {
        String contentString = cleanString.substring(3);
        plrCurrentPosition = contentString.toInt();
        #ifdef DEBUG
          Serial.print("Position: ");Serial.println(contentString);
        #endif
      }

      String uid = record.getId();
      if (uid != "") {
        #ifdef DEBUG
          Serial.print("  ID: ");
          Serial.println(uid);
        #endif
      }
    }
    if (!usableContent){
      #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.println("THIS CARD DOES NOT HAVE THE NECESSARY MESSAGES FOR THE MP3 PLAYER");
      #endif
    }
  } else { // does the card have NDEF messages?
    #ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.println("THIS CARD DOES NOT HAVE MESSAGES AT ALL - NOT USABLE FOR THE MP3 PLAYER");
    #endif
  }
*/
}

//
//        MM      MM   PPPPPP   33333
//        MMMM  MMMM  PP    PP      33
//        MM  MM  MM  PP    PP    3333
//        MM      MM  PPPPPP        33
//        MM      MM  PP        33333
//  BELOW THIS LINE THE MP3 PLAYER CONTROL IS DEFINED
//
uint8_t getVolume(){
  soundVolume = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 0, 100); // map the sensor value to a sound volume

  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.print("last sensor value (if any) was ");Serial.print(lastSensorValue);Serial.print(" / new sensor value is ");Serial.print(sensorValue);Serial.print(" which is a volume of ");Serial.println(soundVolume);
  #endif
  lastSensorValue = sensorValue;
  return (soundVolume);
}

void plrPlayTrack(char dir, char file) {
  String temp = "/";
  temp.concat(dir);
  temp.concat("/");
  temp.concat(file);
  char myFile[temp.length() + 1];
  temp.toCharArray(myFile, sizeof(myFile));

  // mp3 player functions playback
  // Start playing a file, then we can do stuff while waiting for it to finish
  if (! musicPlayer.startPlayingFile(myFile)) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.print("Could not open file ");Serial.println(myFile);
    #endif
    while (1);
  }
  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.print(F("Start playing "));Serial.println(myFile);
  #endif

  while (musicPlayer.playingMusic) {
    // file is now playing in the 'background' so now's a good time
    // to do something else like handling LEDs or buttons :)
    #ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.print(".");
    #endif
    #ifdef LIGHTEFFECTS
      //fader();
    #endif

  }
  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("Done playing ");Serial.println(myFile);
  #endif
}

char plrNext(void){
  char track[12] = "track003.mp3";
  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("plrNext toggled");
  #endif
  #ifdef LIGHTEFFECTS
    //pulse(bluePin);
  #endif

  return track;
}
char plrPrev(void){
  char track[12] = "track001.mp3";
  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println("plrPrevious toggled");
  #endif
  #ifdef LIGHTEFFECTS
    //pulse(greenPin);
  #endif

  return track;
}

void setupSound(){
  // This option uses a pin interrupt. No timers required! But DREQ
  // must be on an interrupt pin. For Uno/Duemilanove/Diecimilla
  // that's Digital #2 or #3
  // See http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/attachInterrupt for other pins
  // *** This method is preferred
  if (! musicPlayer.useInterrupt(VS1053_FILEPLAYER_PIN_INT)) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.println(F("DREQ pin is not an interrupt pin"));
    #endif
    while (1);
  }

  // Start playing a file, then we can do stuff while waiting for it to finish
  if (! musicPlayer.startPlayingFile("hello.mp3")) {
    #ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.println("Could not open file hello.mp3");
    #endif
  } else {
    #ifdef DEBUG
      Serial.print("playing welcome file hello.mp3 ");
    #endif
  }

  // now we play the welcome sound 
  startUpTime = millis();
  while (musicPlayer.playingMusic) {
    if (millis() - startUpTime > 500) {
      #ifdef DEBUG
        Serial.print(".");
      #endif
      startUpTime = millis();
    }
    // file is now playing in the 'background' so now's a good time
    // to do something else like handling LEDs or buttons :)
    #ifdef LIGHTEFFECTS
      //startuplight();
    #endif
  }
  #ifdef DEBUG
    Serial.println(" done");
  #endif
  getVolume();
  musicPlayer.setVolume(soundVolume,soundVolume);
}

//
//        FFFFFF  II  LL      EEEEEE
//        FF      II  LL      EE
//        FFFF    II  LL      EEEE
//        FF      II  LL      EE
//        FF      II  LLLLLL  EEEEEE
// BELOW THIS LINE THE FILE HELPER FUNCTIONS CAN BE FOUND
//
// counts the number of files in directory
//unsigned int countFiles(char dir[]){

unsigned int countFiles(File dir){
  unsigned int counter = 0;
  while (true){
    File entry = dir.openNextFile();
    if (!entry){
      // no more files
      break;
    }
    counter++;
    entry.close();
  }
  dir.close();
  return counter;
}


// store last played track
void rememberCurrentTrack(){

}

// read last played track
void getLastPlayedTrack(){

}

// File listing helper
void printDirectory(File dir, int numTabs) {
   while(true) {
     File entry =  dir.openNextFile();
     if (! entry) {
       // no more files
       //Serial.println("**nomorefiles**");
       break;
     }
     for (uint8_t i=0; i<numTabs; i++) {
       Serial.print('\t');
     }
     Serial.print(entry.name());
     if (entry.isDirectory()) {
       Serial.println("/");
       printDirectory(entry, numTabs+1);
     } else {
       // files have sizes, directories do not
       Serial.print("\t\t");
       Serial.println(entry.size(), DEC);
     }
     entry.close();
   }
}


//
//        LL      EEEEEE  DDDDDD
//        LL      EE      DD    DD
//        LL      EEEE    DD    DD
//        LL      EE      DD    DD
//        LLLLLL  EEEEEE  DDDDDD
//  BELOW THIS LINE THE LIGHT EFFECTS ARE DEFINED
//
// fading organically
void fader(){
  time = millis();
  lightValue1 = 128+127*cos(2*PI/periode*time);
  lightValue2 = 128+127*cos(2*PI/periode*(displace-time));
  lightValue3 = 128+127*cos(2*PI/periode*(2*displace-time));
  analogWrite(redPin, lightValue1);           // sets the value (range from 0 to 255) 
  analogWrite(greenPin, lightValue2);        // sets the value (range from 0 to 255) 
  analogWrite(bluePin, lightValue3);         // sets the value (range from 0 to 255) 
}
// illuminate the 3 led with some fancy lightning during startup
void startuplight(){
  for (int i = 0; i<150; i++) {
    analogWrite(redPin, i);
    analogWrite(greenPin, i);
    analogWrite(bluePin, i);
    delay(10);
  }
  for (int i = 150; i>0; i--) {
    analogWrite(redPin, i);
    analogWrite(greenPin, i);
    analogWrite(bluePin, i);
    delay(10);
  }
  analogWrite(redPin, 0);
  analogWrite(greenPin, 0);
  analogWrite(bluePin, 0);
}
//turn on the desired pin for 5000 milliseconds
void highlight(int pin){
  time = millis();
  while (millis()<time+5000){
    analogWrite(pin, 255);
  }
  analogWrite(pin, 0);
}
//turn on the desired pin for 5000 milliseconds
void flash(int pin){
  time = millis();
  while (millis()<time+1000){
    analogWrite(pin, 255);
  }
  analogWrite(pin, 0);
}
//turn on the desired pin for 5000 milliseconds
void pulse(int pin){
  for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
    time = millis();
    while (millis()<time+2500){
      analogWrite(pin, 255);
    }
    analogWrite(pin, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to open the file then pass that file. Or have your function accept a char array and do the file opening itself. Either way, at some point, you will need to open the file.

Comment: Actually that function does not open a file at all. It simply counts the number of files in a directory. But you have a point nonetheless. Maybe best would be to restructure the function and find a way to count files in a directory without the need to pass a File descriptor to the function. Would you have, by any chance an idea on how to count files in a directory where the directory name is past as a char array???

Comment: As far as filesystems are concerned (in general) a directory is just another file. You just use special functions to read the contents of it. To do any operation on a directory you need to open it. Like a file.

Comment: Thank you so very much. As posted below, I was really blindfolded here. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

OMG. I'm so sorry for posting such a stupid question. And I'm also sorry for not seeing the obvious even after Majenko pointed me to it.

Of course I need to call the function like this:

```
numberOfFiles = countFiles(SD.open(plrCurrentFolder));
```

That way, the directory get's opened and my function can operate on it.

I see I still have to learn a lot :-)